# What's the best way to handle form data in wordpress in the backend?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, controller

Right now I'm simply sending the data to my page template but I don't think it's good to have all that logic together with the markup with the page, especially since I want to have multiple forms on the page which would lead to even more code that isn't really relevant to the view of the page. In another cms (concrete) I have set up routes that point to a custom controller to handle the form data, can I do something similar or is there a different approach for this in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by separating controller logic from the html template. Look at Timber for example: https://github.com/timber/timber

Then your page template will look more like a controller and you could avoid messy code from handling everything in one file.

Your page template could look like this:

```
<?php

    $data = Timber::get_context();
    $data['page'] = $page;
    if (isset($_POST['whatever']))
    {
        $data['whatever'] = 'It works!';
        Timber::render('views/whatever-posted.twig', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        Timber::render('views/landing.twig', $data);
    }
```

IMO it is much cleaner code than mixing up PHP/HTML